# Do you know what type of insect this is?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found these in my appartment (we live in a half basement). It's been three so far and I can't find the thing anywhere in insect lists, etc. Could you tell me what type of insect this is?

[image: Alive]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 900 different species of Crickets but I would say it is a Camel Cricket based on the info provided.[image]

Comment: As camel crickets often live in basements, you are probably right. It might be good to add a reference, for [example](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhaphidophoridae) Some hilarious info on how to get rid of then can be found [here](http://colinpurrington.com/2012/getting-rid-camel-crickets/#comments)

Comment: @RHA Why would anyone get rid of such harmless insect?

Answer (score 4):

This is a camel cricket (family **Rhaphidophoridae**); T. H. Hubbell's 1936 monograph on the genus *Ceuthophilus* has a key to the North American genera then known (and those added since are not found in Canada).  The photograph does resemble specimens of *Ceuthophilus* that I have collected and may well be that genus.