# What kind of grasshopper-like insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

We found this thing in our basement. Not quite an average grasshopper. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Please include your location, or at least a country and state. That will make your question much easier to answer.

Comment: Looks like a [cave cricket](https://www.google.com/search?q=cave+cricket&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAwunR2-bXAhVE44MKHRYXBXYQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=663) to me!

Comment: This is potentially a duplicate of [the question asked here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44015/do-you-know-what-type-of-insect-this-is/59683); if not a duplicate, the species involved appear closely related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a "cave cricket", in the family Rhaphidophoridae. These are common in basements, and harmless.