# Insect identification request. Long anteni. Grasshopper legs

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Found in solo cup used to catch drips from toilet valve. East coast of U.S.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you know what type of insect this is?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/44015/do-you-know-what-type-of-insect-this-is)

Answer (score 2):

That is a camel cricket, Rhaphidophoridae. https://www.pestworld.org/pest-guide/occasional-invaders/camel-crickets/ 
Likely some species of *Ceuthophilus*